# Embedding an Iframe having CSP 2.0 in a mobile app: "frame-ancestors" issue

Tags: cordova, iframe, ionic-framework, content-security-policy

Building an hybrid app with the Ionic framework, I need to embed to one of my page an Iframe. My problem is that the page loaded with the iframe does have the following CSP:

```
"frame-ancestors http://foo.somedomain.com"
```

Which works just fine on my browser. However whenever I try this on the application itself the content is not loaded due to:

> Refused to display 'http://foo.somedomain.com' in a frame because an
>   ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive
>   "frame-ancestors http://*.somedomain.com"

That make sense as the app request doesn't have a domain.

So my question is simply:

**How can I identify my app (iOS and Android) in order to go through the frame-ancestors CSP?**

I see that I can pass many things to that frame-ancestor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors but I don't see how to validate that the request is coming from a mobile application.

Comment: did u find the solution for this?

Comment: nope....  wasn't able to find one... had to move on.

Comment: The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors#Syntax) suggest that a host source can either be a name or IP address, so maybe identifying the app by IP address could be a solution. At least if the IP address is static...

Answer (score 3):

On android, you can follow the steps at https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to specify a custom domain and scheme to use. Namely:

```xml
<preference name="Hostname" value="app" />
```

```xml
<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
```

The issue lies in Ionic's use of a webserver on iOS. Still trying to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the domain's web server, and you can set a cookie for only ionic requests (like when you log in to the site) then you could optionally exclude the CSP for requests coming from ionic by detecting the set cookie:

For Apache:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "ionic_cookie=1" is_ionic
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http://foo.somedomain.com" env=!is_ionic
```