# CSP Frame ancestor iframe Ionic

Tags: typescript, iframe, ionic2, content-security-policy

Is there a way to bypass Content Security Policy frame ancestor on iframe in Ionic 2 TypeScript? I have getting error

> refused to display 'http://test.domain.com' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive "frame-ancestors http://*.domain.com"

*It is working fine on my site, which has the domain whitelisted on CSP, probably almost same problem as this: [Embedding an Iframe having CSP 2.0 in a mobile app: "frame-ancestors" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957787/embedding-an-iframe-having-csp-2-0-in-a-mobile-app-frame-ancestors-issue)*

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: @JustCarty I to setup proxy like that one, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue on CSP Frame ancestor.

Comment: are you working on the same project as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739344/csp-frame-ancestor-ionic-v2) user?

Comment: Goodday! yes @SurajRao